# What is the difference between these two differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know how to solve both of these problems but I don't know why I solve each of these problems differently. How can I solve the second problem the way I solved the first one? Or is that not possible?

1. If $\frac{dy}{dx}=y\sec^2(x)$ and $y=5$ when $x=0$, then $y=$

a) $e^{\tan(x)}+4$

b) $e^{\tan(x)}+5$

c) $5e^{\tan(x)}$

d) $\tan(x)+5$

e) $\tan(x)+5e^x$

To solve this I found $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for each of the answer choices and answer choice c) gives $\frac{dx}{dy}=5e^{\tan(x)}\sec^2(x)$ and since $y=5e^{\tan x}$, this is of the form $\frac{dy}{dx}=y\sec^2 x$

2. Which of the following is the solution to the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{y+x} $ with the initial condition $y(0)=-\ln(4)$?

a) $y=-x-\ln(4)$

b) $y=x-\ln(4)$

c) $y=-\ln(-e^x+5)$

d) $y=-\ln(e^x+3)$

e) $y=\ln(e^x+3)$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=e^y*e^x$

$\frac{dy}{y}=e^xdx$

$\int \frac{dy}{y}= \int e^xdx$

$-e^{-y}=e^x +C$

$e^{-y}=-e^x +C$

$\ln[e^{-y}]=\ln[-e^x +C]$

$-y=\ln(-e^x+C)$

$y=-\ln(-e^x+C)$

This is answer choice C.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same thing on the first equation as you did on the second equation.

It's called separation of variables.

Start with

$$\dfrac{dy}{y}= \sec^2(x)dx$$

and integrate both sides separately!

Comment: yes but I wanted to know about solving the second question with the method that I solved the first question

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same in the second problem: $dy=-d(\ln(-e^x+5))=\frac{e^xdx}{-e^x+5}$ or
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=e^xe^y$$ because if $y=-\ln(-e^x+5)$ then $e^y=\frac{1}{-e^x+5}$

Comment: ohh okay thank you! So when should I use which method? is this always true?

Comment: @user130306: usually I solve the equation (second method) then I can verify solution using the first method. It's probably easier to solve one equation then to find five derivatives :)

Comment: sorry I'm just still a little confused because I can do the same thing you did for the other answer choices. so for example answer choice d in question 2 would give $dy/dx=\frac{e^x}{e^x+3}$ so in this case $e^{y}$ could also be $\frac{1}{e^x+3}$ but this is not the right answer..

Comment: @user130306: in choice d we will get $dy/dx=-e^xe^y$, you forgot the minus sign

Comment: got it. but for answer choice C) how come we can see that $e^y=\frac{1}{-e^x+5}$ when we have a $-e^x$ in the term?

Comment: and for answer choice e) we would get $dy/dx=\frac{e^x}{e^x+3}$ so why can't we have $e^{y}=(e^x +3)^{-1}$?

Comment: @user130306: for choice e) we have that $e^y=e^x+3$. Have to be careful with those signs :) Again, a differential equation usually has a family of solutions, that's why the best approach is to find general solution first then look for a specific solution using the initial conditions. In real life we usually do not have answers that we can plug in and check.

Comment: how is $e^y = e^x+3$? the derivative is $dy/dx=\frac{e^x}{e^x+3}$ so $e^y=\frac{1}{e^x +3} = (e^x +3)^{-1}$